# Sending html instead of js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I try to configure webpack with express. But in bundle.js in browser cosole, I see that there is the same code as in html file, not js as expected. This is my server configuration:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack/webpack.config');
const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.get(/.*/, function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
  console.log(webpackConfig);
});

app.use(function(res, req, next) {
    const err = new Error('You have 404 error!');
    err.status = 404;
});

let server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(3000, function onListening() {
    const address = server.address();
    console.log('This is port ' + address.port);
});
```

And this is webpack:

```
require('babel-polyfill').default;
const path = require('path');

const common = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, '../src'),
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '../dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: 'dist/',
        library: "home"
    },
    watch: true,
    watchOptions:{
        aggregateTimeout: 100
    },
    module: {
        loaders:[{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loaders: ['babel-loader'],
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        }]
    }
}

module.exports = common;
```

in index.html I include js like this:

```
src="/dist/bundle.js"
```

The structure of folders is:

```
.
├── bin
│   └── index.js
├── index.html
├── package.json
├── server.js
├── src
│   └── index.js
└── webpack
    └── webpack.config.js
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes we can use Html instead of Js. Because it's easy to understand and there is no confusion for the students who are at entry level.

Comment: No, I mean that instead of webpack bundling file with js it plugged index.html file